# Android - Force fragment to detach / exit while it is still going through its creation lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, garbage-collection, android-lifecycle

I find that when my app goes from the background to the foreground, and the OS kills my process while it was in the background, the fragment goes through its creation life-cycle all over again. There are some scenarios where I'd like for my fragment to not start. I find that even if I request my fragment manager to remove the fragment in `onCreate()`, it still goes through other life cycle methods. Any way I can get it to do a clean exit while it is still in the creation life-cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **NO**, you cannot "short-circuit" the `Fragment` life-cycle in any way. The framework won't let you.

Now I'll give the long answer, the **WHY**. The lives of various classes, including `Fragment`s and `Activity`s, are designed to follow a set of *life-cycle callbacks* for the reason that the GC has to manage the memory of a large variety of objects (such as `View`s, `LoaderManager`s and many other things) in a properly arranged sequence to ensure correct cleanup. If you try to perform a "clean exit", as you call it, then you as the programmer have to take the responsibility of cleaning up the memory, which the framework won't allow you to do.

The only time a "short-circuit" or "clean-exit" of the kind you describe happens is in the very rare case when the OS kills a foreground app (extremely rare). In that case the memory is simply reclaimed by the OS kernel, not the GC.

So you need to introspect about what you actually want to achieve as a consequence of preventing a `Fragment` from completing its life-cycle. Whatever your underlying intent is, trying to accomplish that by circumventing the `Fragment` life-cycle is a wrong-headed approach.

**Further considerations:**

I think you may be looking for the [`detach()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach%28android.app.Fragment%29) method, though its hard to tell without understanding what you really want to do. The same `Fragment` can be brought back to visible state by calling [`attach()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach%28android.app.Fragment%29).

Comment: At what point would it be meaningful to ask it to destroy itself? (I can attempt to hide it up until that point)

Comment: Let me ask the real question: what exactly do you hope to accomplish as a side-effect of "destroying" a `Fragment`, or circumventing its life-cycle ?

Comment: not have it be visible. I want the activity to run without the fragment under certain circumstances if its been destroyed.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the delay, I solved it by waiting for the creation lifecycle to complete, the last method being onActivirtCreated(), and called dismiss in that method

Comment: great ... good for you :) ... i suppose you could also try using `detach()`.